# Finding parallel and perpendicular vectors when |a|=1 and a.b=3?

Tags: vectors

Two vectors A and B lie in the same plane and it is given that |A|=1 and A.B=3. I have to find, in terms of A and B, the vector U, parallel to A, and the vector V perpendicular to A. Both of these vectors lie in the same plane such that U+V=A+B.

What I have done:
Any vector that is parallel to a will be of the form kA, where k is a real number. Thus I have said U+kA=A+B and so u=(1-k)A + B. For V and A to be perpendicular V.A=0 and so by a rearrangement of the dot product formula v=0(A+B). I am stuck on this problem and I wonder whether anyone could give me some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $k,s,t\in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\vec U=k\vec A \quad \vec V=s\vec A+t\vec B$$

since

$$\vec A\cdot \vec V=0\implies s|\vec A|^2+t\vec A\cdot \vec B=0\implies s=-3t \implies \vec V=-3t\vec A+t\vec B$$

then

$$\vec U+\vec V=\vec A+\vec B\implies k\vec A-3t\vec A+t\vec B=\vec A+\vec B\implies t=1 \quad k=4$$

therefore

> $$\vec U=4 \vec A \quad \vec V=-3\vec A+\vec B$$

Comment: could you help me with the second part? I am completley stumped!

Comment: @TCarr what is the second part?

Comment: The vector c is not parallel to the plane of a and b and is such that c.a = -2 and c.b=2. Given that |b| = 5 find, in terms of a,b and c, vectors U,V and W such that U and V are parallel to u and v respectively, W is perpendicular to the plane of a and b and U + V + W= a+b+c ( i used capitals for a and b in the above question)

Comment: @TCarr I can't see it in the OP

Comment: (a) Given that|a|= 1 and a•b= 3, find, in terms of a and b, a vector u parallel to a and a vector v perpendicular toa
, both lying in the plane Π, such that u + v = a + b.
[7]

The vector c is not parallel to the plane Π and is such that c•a = −2 and c•b= 2.
(b) Given that |b|= 5, find, in terms of a, b and c, vectors U, V and W such that U and V are parallel to u and v respectively, W
is perpendicular to the plane Π, and U+V+W=a+b+c

Comment: This is the full question and I cant do b. I have tried saying w=a x b and so |w| = |a|.|v| which allowed me to calculate |w|. I tried doing some stuff after that but started to lose the whole numbers

Comment: @TCarr ok I take a look!

Comment: @TCarr There is a great confusion with symbols here and in the other OP, for examble since U+V+W=a+b+c it follow that c=W, which I guess is not correct for the giving. You need to fix the text of the OP.

Comment: the one here is the correct one

Comment: the one i posted that is, i changed the symbols on the other question to be in keeping with the new question

Comment: Yes but it seems that there is a problem, since U and V are paralle to u and v theu lie in the plane of a and b, thus from U+V+W=a+b+c you must have that W=c which doesn't seem correct. Do you agree with that? Please verify the text.

Comment: everything is correct it would appear... Then that means U=u,V=v andW=w?

Comment: No it is not possible since  c•a = −2 and c•b= 2 and W is perpendicular to the plane it can't be c=W. There is something wrong in the problem setting.

Comment: yes i see what you mean. It must be incorrect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72520/discussion-between-tcarr-and-gimusi).